# How to linkify to in-built apps like Contacts?

Tags: android, textview, linkify

I have an empty TextView set for my `ListView`. When there is no data, it shows the empty text, where I have description that they should go to Contacts application.

How can I linkify "Contacts" word so when tapped opens the Contacts application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting up a `Linkify` rule to the `content://` URL of the contact in question. Though I am not certain what the pattern would be -- `Linkify` is designed for things that are obvious regexes. If all you want is for them to tap on the description as a whole, set up an `OnClickListener` for it.

Comment: I need the uri for the Contacts application, not for a specific contact. Do you know?

Comment: There is no `Uri` for an application, per se. You can try using the `Uri` to the `Contacts` collection and see if that works. There should be a `CONTENT_URI` somewhere in the `ContactsContract` set of classes/interfaces.